# smtpmail error "An unexpected TLS packet was received"

Tags: emacs, smtp

I write emails in emacs via `mu4e`. If I specify `starttls` instead of `ssl` in the following code, smtpmail can send the messages:

```
;; sending mail (see Appendix B.3.2 of the mu4e manual)
(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      messsage-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it; use smtpmail for sending mails
      smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl; starttls works here, why not ssl?
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "mail.uni.edu"; default smtp server
      smtpmail-smtp-server "mail.uni.edu"; host name of the SMTP server
      smtpmail-smtp-service "smtp"); controls the port on the server to contact
```

However, for `ssl`, I obtain (output of *Messages*):

```
Sending via mail...
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
gnutls.el: (err=[-15] An unexpected TLS packet was received.) boot: (:priority NORMAL :hostname mail.ethz.ch :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits 256 :trustfiles (/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt) :crlfiles nil :keylist nil :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :verify-hostname-error nil :callbacks nil)
gnutls-negotiate: GnuTLS error: #<process smtpmail>, -15
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [100 times]
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `"smtp"` by `465` and it works.